# How to segregate .csv file by considering selected data in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have `.csv` file and I want to separate selected data column and write those selected data to new .csv files.

The charging and discharging are stored in a `.csv` file with a fixed format. Each file contains 2 children details.This button event handler should segregate the `main.csv` file in to separate `.csv` files depending on  conditions:

if only generate new .csv file by considering following condition.

**CutMark(1,2) = TRUE for an entire period of a particular “Pass”**

**E.g:**

•   If all  are active(CutMark1 and CutMark2 all are TRUE) during the entire period of “Pass” traversal from “FALSE-TRUE-FALSE-TRUE” (“Discharge-Charge-Discharge-Charge”), the following files should be created by this tool [totally 8 files]:

Discharge1_CH1.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1 )

Discharge1_CH2.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2 )

Charge1_CH1.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1 )
 Charge1_CH2.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2 )

Discharge2_CH1.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1 ) Discharge2_CH2.csv(with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2 )

Charge2_CH1.csv (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1 )

Charge2_CH2.csv  (with column heders Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2 )

Like that I want to generate new `.csv` file.
This is my sample .csv file:

```
Date,Pass,CutMark1,Marks1,CutMark2,Marks2,
22/06/2017 13:04:18,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,35,
22/06/2017 13:04:20,FALSE,TRUE,35,FALSE,35,
22/06/2017 13:04:35,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,100,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,38,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:38,FALSE,FALSE,35,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:39,FALSE,FALSE,35,FALSE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:40,FALSE,FALSE,35,TRUE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:41,FALSE,FALSE,55,TRUE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:42,FALSE,FALSE,55,TRUE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:44,FALSE,FALSE,38,TRUE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:45,TRUE,FALSE,38,TRUE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:46,TRUE,FALSE,38,TRUE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:48,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:49,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,25,
22/06/2017 13:04:50,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,45,
22/06/2017 13:04:52,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,60,
22/06/2017 13:04:53,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,80,
22/06/2017 13:04:54,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,80,
22/06/2017 13:04:56,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,75,
22/06/2017 13:04:57,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,90,
22/06/2017 13:04:58,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,88,
22/06/2017 13:05:00,TRUE,TRUE,55,TRUE,23,
22/06/2017 13:05:01,TRUE,TRUE,55,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:02,TRUE,TRUE,20,TRUE,78,
22/06/2017 13:05:04,TRUE,TRUE,45,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:05,TRUE,TRUE,85,TRUE,69,
22/06/2017 13:05:06,TRUE,TRUE,62,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:08,TRUE,TRUE,100,TRUE,35,
```

This my code for button handler:

```
  using System.Globalization;

  public static string dateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";


  private void btnSeperateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int discharge_counter = 0;
            int charge_counter = 0;

            if (tbOutputFilePath2 != null)
            {

                List<DrawNew> ObservingData = new List<DrawNew>(); // List to store all available DrawNew objects from the CSV

                // Loops through each lines in the CSV
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(outputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
                {

                    string[] valuesCsvLine = line.Split(',');
                    DrawNew mngInstance = new DrawNew();

                    mngInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
                    mngInstance.Pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    mngInstance.CutMark1 = (valuesCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ?true: false);
                    mngInstance.Marks1 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[3]);                 
                    mngInstance.CutMark2 = (valuesCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    mngInstance.Marks2 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[5]); 

                    ObserveData.Add(mngInstance);

                    if (mngInstance.Pass==true && mngInstance.CutMark1==true)
                    {


                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.CutMark1 == true)
                    {

                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == true && mngInstance.CutMark2 == true)
                    {

                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.CutMark2 == true )
                    {

                    }            
                }
            }
```

This is the class for storing data of `.csv` file:

```
 class DrawNew
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } // property to store Date 
        public bool Pass { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public bool CutMark1 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public int Marks1 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep
        public bool CutMark2 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public int Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep 
     }
```

If you can please correct my code as my condition.I want to create new .csv file as my condition.and I want to ask how i separate "Pass" column in time to time In my example FALSE-TRUE-FALSE-TRUE and want save in different name as given above.please help me to solve this.If can very appreciated.

Comment: How you do it is kinda personal preference, but I dont see a problem.. so why the post?

Comment: @BugFinder,I want to ask how i seperate "Pass" column in time to time In here FALSE-TRUE-FALSE-TRUE

Comment: sadly that statement doesnt make sense to me.. but if you're wanting to write the different conditions to different files, then do just that.. in each of the if statements

Comment: @BugFinder,Thank you sir,Now I am trying to do that.can you say ,how i create .csv file.in this if condition.please give me a example.

Comment: you know its a text file right?, just write your data out.... you already have the original csv unless you're changing the format, just write it out to the correct file..

Comment: @BugFinder,Sir if you have time ,please tell me in my example `"Pass"column` has FALSE and TRUE.Can you say how I create new .CSV file like this,first meet False rows are in false1.csv second meet True rows are in true1c.csv and again meet False then false2.csv again meet True then true2.csv like that.how I get those.please give me a help sir

Comment: Firstly Im not male, second, you've already parsed them and have your if's ready, so use a different file to write to and write out the line you first started with.. We arent here to be your parents and do it for you

Comment: @BugFinder,oh sorry for my disturbance and wrong designation.I do not have any person to clear my dought.that's why I asked in here.any way thank you for your advise.